# How does a channel for a signal inside another channel work together?

Tags: go

I have recently started my study of go and am trying to understand how channels work. I'm reading a book there they give such an example:

**At times you will be working with channels from disparate parts of your system.
Unlike with pipelines, you can’t make any assertions about how a channel will behave
when code you’re working with is canceled via its done channel. That is to say, you
don’t know if the fact that your goroutine was canceled means the channel you’re
reading from will have been canceled. For this reason we need to wrap our read from the channel with a select statement that also selects from a done channel. This is perfectly fine, but
doing so takes code that’s easily read like this**

```
func orDone(done, c <-chan interface{}) <-chan interface{} {
    valStream := make(chan interface{})
    go func() {
        defer close(valStream)
        for {
            select {
            case <-done:
                return
            case v, ok := <-c:
                if ok == false {
                    return
                }
                select {
                case valStream <- v:
                case <-done:
                    fmt.Println("inside", count)
                }
            }
        }
    }()
    return valStream
}
```

And I don't quite understand how closing a channel through a done channel works.
Let's say I have this code:

```
func main() {
    done1 := make(chan interface{})
    done2 := make(chan interface{})
    inf := infGenerator(done1)

    for v := range orDone(done2, inf) {
        if count == 3 {
            close(done1)
        }
        count++
        fmt.Println(v)
    }

}
```

If , for example , the first channel is closed , then everything is clear , it will be executed

```
if ok == false {
     return
}
```

But I don 't quite understand how the program works when we close the second channel instead of 1.

First, the program goes to

```
case <-done:
    fmt.Println("inside", count)
}
```

And then it gets into the upper one. And I don't understand why it works this way.Shouldn't the nested `case <-done:` get the closure message and pick it up? Or if we close the channel, then the signal about it is not taken from the channel? And if there is a chance that another case can be executed when closing ?

Comment: There is no such thing as a closure message. Reading from a closed channel (assuming its buffer is empty) returns immediately with `ok` = `false`. Always.

Comment: @tkausl And will **for** continue if one of the threads is closed?

Comment: `threads`? You meant channels? It might continue as long as there are items available in `c` because as far as I remember, the order in which they are hit is unspecified if they all are available immediately, however as soon as `<-c` would block, it will hit the `<-done` case and return.

Comment: @tkausl Thanks for the reply. Can you help me understand if I close done from the outside, but there will still be elements in **c** then in such cases, the program should immediately exit or will it continue to read?

Comment: It _might_ continue. I'm not exactly sure, haven't written Go in a long time.

Comment: See the language spec section on [select](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Select_statements) - "If one or more of the communications can proceed, a single one that can proceed is chosen via a uniform pseudo-random selection". So you cannot predict whether it will continue or not. Note that you need to be careful with algorithms like this ([for example](https://go.dev/play/p/HDSYe4KNgQn)) and its often best to use the closure of the source channel to indicate that the work is complete. The [tour](https://go.dev/tour/concurrency/1) may help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `infGenerator` closes `inf` after receiving the `done` signal:

Closing `done1` results in closing `inf`, which causes `orDone` to return as you said.

If you close `done` instead, the function `orDone` executes the nested `done` case, then the outer `done` case, simply because the nested `done` case did not return from the function. It reads the `done` signal, continues looping, and the loop reads the `done` signal again and returns.

An unbuffered channel does not hold any data. Thus, if you close an unbuffered channel, any goroutines blocked reading from it will be enabled with `false`. Any further read attempts will also immediately return `false`. Because of this, closing a channel is a good way to broadcast completion to all goroutines.